# Typescript: define the type of a parameter of a function as a function with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have created a `compose` function like this

```
const composeTyped = <T, U, R>(f: (x: T) => U, g: (y: U) => R) => (x: T) => g(f(x));
```

It seems to me that both `f` and `g` are functions of type `fGeneric` which is defined as

```
type fGeneric = <T, R>(arg: T) => R;
```

My problem is that I do not understand if and how I could use the type `fGeneric` to specify the type of `f` and `g` in `composedType`. To be more clear, if I do like this

```
const composeTyped_ = <T, U, R>(f: fGeneric, g: fGeneric) => (x: T) => g(f(x));
```

the function `composeTyped_` is assigned the type `(x: T) => unknown`. What I would like to obtain though is the type `(x: T) => R`.

Comment: Btw, here https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose, in my blog, you can find some crazy typings for `compose` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `fGeneric` so that it accepts generic type arguments:

```
type fGeneric<T, R> = (arg: T) => R;
```

Then you can defined `composeTyped_` like so:

```
const composeTyped_ = <T, U, R>(
  f: fGeneric<T, U>,
  g: fGeneric<U, R>
) => (x: T) => g(f(x));
```

This should now work nicely:

```
declare const f: (str: string) => number

declare const g: (num: number) => null

composeTyped_(f, g)

// Argument of type '(num: number) => null' is not assignable to parameter of type 
//   'fGeneric<number, string>'.
//  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
composeTyped_(g, f)
```

Comment: thanks it works well. I was making the mistake of defining the function type like this `type fGeneric = <T, R>(arg: T) => R;`. By the way the compiler does not complain when I define such a type but now, after your answer, I am struggling to understand which kind of type this could be. In other words, would you be able to explain what this type definition means: `type fGeneric = <T, R>(arg: T) => R;`?

Comment: `type fGeneric = <T, R>(arg: T) => R` only allows `T` and `R` to be inferred automatically. In practice, that means that `fGeneric` defined that way is almost impossible to use. A simpler example is `type Identity = <T>(arg: T) => T`. That type can only be used in a definition like `const identity: Identity = arg => arg`. However, if you type it as `type Identity<T> = (arg: T) => T` then you could do something like `const exclaim: Identity<string> = (str) => str.concat("!")`.